# multiple mysqli multi_query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to query mysql db with about 3000 queries, instead sending each query to db server, I create the huge query of `INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY` statements and send it to the db server. I found mysqli's multi_query very usefull but then I need to insert into 5 different tables, each of about 3000 queries. Therefore I use this code:

```
$this->_mysqli->multi_query($values[1]);
while ($this->_mysqli->next_result()) {;}
$this->_mysqli->multi_query($values[2]);
while ($this->_mysqli->next_result()) {;}
$this->_mysqli->multi_query($values[3]);
while ($this->_mysqli->next_result()) {;}
$this->_mysqli->multi_query($values[4]);
while ($this->_mysqli->next_result()) {;}
$this->_mysqli->multi_query($values[5]);
while ($this->_mysqli->next_result()) {;}
```

But only first statement passes others wont. Any ideas why?

EDIT: if I add `or die()` I get this message `MySQL server has gone away`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the [packet is too large](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: You made my day. Thanks for your post. I did max_allowed_packet = 16M and it was working like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Increase max_allowed_packet in your MySQL config

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```